How to reference embedded pdfs
I have some pdfs, one used as a master and the others as files to be embedded into it, and I want to make out of them a single one where I can click and open the embedded files.
Ideally, the final result should be similar to the LaTeX navigator package, implementing something similar to the \openfilelink{}{}-LaTeX command.
Here the expected output, send-anywhere.com/web/downloads/KIA65C2R, using LaTeX navigator.
I haven't found yet a way to do it with PyMuPDF.
Example of files structure:
main_directory:

master.pdf
embedded_file1.pdf
embedded_file2.pdf

References:

doc: embfile_add
embedding-files
LaTeX - navigator: on Tex.SE, doc
expected output: send-anywhere.com/web/downloads/KIA65C2R


Embed files with PyMuPDF:
import fitz


def add_embed_files(src:str, *files_to_embed:list[str]) -> fitz.Document:
    doc = fitz.open(src) # open main document

    # embed with the file name and the data
    apply_template_embedded_file_name = f"{{}}_EMBEDDED_IN_{os.path.basename(src)}".format
    for f in files_to_embed:
        embedded_doc = fitz.open(f) # open document you want to embed
        embedded_data = embedded_doc.tobytes() # get the document byte data as a buffer

        doc.embfile_add(apply_template_embedded_file_name(f), embedded_data)
        embedded_doc.close()

    return doc


path_master_pdf:str = #
paths_files_to_embed:list[str] = #

path_master_with_embeddings = path_master_pdf.removesuffix('.pdf') + '_with_embeddings.pdf'


doc = add_embed_files(path_master_pdf, *paths_files_to_embed)
doc.save(path_master_with_embeddings)
doc.close()


Thanks for the clarification, and yes, my description seems to fall perfectly in the categories that you mentioned. My problem is that I  need a way to provide a self-contained file. If I forward the auxiliaries files individually, and use ie LaTeX hyperref package, then the links will be broken if the addressee don't use the same file structure... and that's exactly my case!

I know how to automatize the whole stuffs with suprocess but I would like a more Pythonic solution

But the examples of your links aren't just a pdf embedding other pdfs? This can be achieve also with PyMuPDF (ie see my code snapshot), what I would like to have is some text pointing (like a link) to a specific embedded file. Here an example achieved with LaTeX navigator, sendanywhe.re/KIA65C2R

Notice that not all PDF Viewer supports such feature: with Firefox it works, with Atril not
